# How to Connect kafka with SQL server?

Tags: docker, jdbc, apache-kafka, streaming

I am beginner in Apache Kafka and want to stream the data from SQL server using Apache Kafka, I am using docker since I have windows. I want clear steps to do that. Thank you

I tried to use docker compose and downloaded the needed services but all ports didn't work, gives me unable to connect!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.